# bash command substitution failing with ( character

Tags: bash, glob

I am running a bash script which is as follows :

```
n=`ls /tmp/abc/*-(2|3).20150406.txt | wc -l`;
```

but it is giving syntax error at this line saying 
command substitution: line 1 unexpected token `('

The same command runs fine without the script on console. Am i missing anything here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What pattern are you trying to match? Could you please add a one or two match examples?

Comment: Pattern I am matching is  a file name like : /tmp/abc/run-2.20150406 or /tmp/abc/run-3.20150406 or /tmp/abc/run-29.20150406

Comment: OK, Fixed & undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you would like to match this filename pattern:

```
<anything><dash><2 or 3><anything><20150406.txt>
```

For example, matching:

```
file-2.20150406.txt
file-3.20150406.txt
run-29.20150406.txt
```

But not:

```
file-4.20150406.txt
run-29.20150406
```

The following should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=`find /tmp/abc -regex ".*-[23].*20150406.txt" | wc -l`
echo $n
```

In general, [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) is more suitable for regexen than `ls`.

Comment: Adam , this find based solution works but I need to match two sets differently . First set needs to match 2, 3, 29,30,32 ,8 so [23] won't suffice . second set i need to match 1,15,28,9,33 and thats why I was looking for a regex match against a class of integers . Can you please provide me two regex expression which mach both these sets independently.  I tried [238] for set 1 but it also matches 33 which is failing.

Comment: For that, I'd  use two or three consecutive `find` commands, and summarize the `wc`-s or the results - or even better, write a Python script for that. The former is quite basic; I will happily elaborate my answer on the later.

Comment: @TopCoder please edit your question and include this information. You are asking us to fly blind here. You need to always include all relevant details and limitations of your task.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `extglob` here to match few chosen numbers like this:

```
shopt -s extglob
printf "%s\n" /tmp/abc/*-@(2|3|29).20150406.txt
```

It will print:

```
/tmp/abc/run-2.20150406.txt
/tmp/abc/run-29.20150406.txt
/tmp/abc/run-3.20150406.txt
```

To count them:

```
printf "%s\n" /tmp/abc/*-@(2|3|29).20150406.txt | wc -l
```